# Can I view the content of an url using HTML?

Tags: html

I have a url and is it possible to view it contents? like an `<img>` tag just put the source on it and it display the image. Mine is like put the contents of a link in a `<div>` is that possible?

Comment: dont have any ideas, not found any in google or i just use a wrong term

Comment: If you want to show link content on your site, use `iframe`. If not, improve the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use an [`<iframe>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5) instead of a `<div>`:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com" width="500" height="400">
    Text for very old browsers that don't support iframes.
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this  [Jquery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('#div').load('url_to_page.php');
```

OR

```
$.get('url_to_page.php', function(data) {
  $('#div').html(data);
});
```

if you want to see source you should use `text()` intead of `html()`

Comment: in this case html that will be get from url will be inserted in div

Comment: Then you misunderstood the "using HTML" part of the question. You're *using* JavaScript to get the HTML of another page to place in an element.

Comment: An IFRAME won't display anything without a browser aither. HTML is a language you can't display anything `in HTML`.

Comment: if you need see source - instead of html() use text(). in this case all '<' and '>' will be encoded

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript:

```
var element = document.getElementById ( 'id-of-your-element' )
element.innerHTML = 'your HTML source'
```